# Smoothing all the intersection for GPX track points?

Tags: qgis, gps, generalization, smoothing

I have a.GPX Track file that has too many intersections. I want to smooth out due to all the intersection

Currently, I'm trying to figure out a way to smooth out this track file. The intersections are not smooth and interfering with my perimeter area of these specific sections. Is there any way to smooth this out or will I have to create a new shapefile from scratch?

[image: Current problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can substantially reduce the intersections with an approach deleting vertices that are closer to each other than a certain distance. The idea behind this solution is that using GPS tracking, such intersections are created when you're not moving (or only slowly) and the GPS receiver records repeating points at more or less the same location, but with small random displacements. This results in clusters of vertices. When you are moving however, you will get vertices along a path with higher intervalls in between.

1. Extract vertices from your path.
2. On the resulting point layer, create a new field `dist_nearest` that calculates the distance to the next vertex. Use the following expression to calculate the field. The `overlay_nearest` function is [available since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core):  for older versions have a look at the
   [refFunctions Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions).

```
length (
    make_line (
        $geometry, 
        array_first (
            overlay_nearest( 
                @layer, 
                $geometry, 
                limit:=1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

3. Use selct by expression using `"dist_nearest" < 3` - where `dist_nearest` is the field you created and 3 is a value you should change: it's the maximum distance (the threshold) to the next vertex up until which neighboring vertices can be deleted. The value depends on your data, observ in the map canvas which points get selected and reduce/increase the selection threshold accordingly.
4. Delete the selected vertices.
5. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Points to path` to re-connect the remaining vertices. In the drop down menu `Order field`, select  `vertex_index`: this field was created automatically in step 1.

Using this approach, I was able to get the red line, starting from the black input line. White dots: original vertices, red dots: remaining vertices.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you I shall give this a try once I get back from the field and let you know how it went.

Comment: So I could not get step 2.) or step 3.) completed. However, My work around was to just trim the vertices Manually and then Do step 5.) My be That im a bit on the new side, so I dont fully understand the coding.

Comment: In step 2, use field calculator: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=field%20calculator#using-the-field-calculator